# How many kills does it take to unlock new subclass abilities?

Tags: destiny-2

With the release of Destiny 2's latest expansion Forsaken, new sub-class abilities and supers have been added to the game.

These require the acquisition of a Seed of Light, and then the completion of a mission for the Traveler.

However I used the opportunity to complete my Triumph for using each sub-class super in a single activity. This left me with the three sub-class skills still locked.

The skills state that you have to unlock them by defeating enemies using the super ability, but gives no indication of how many.

How many enemies do I need to defeat with my new super ability to unlock each of the three remaining sub-class abilities?

Comment: I don't know the exact amount, but if you hover over the symbol for your subclass it shows percent complete. Better than nothing.

Comment: It took me about 5 - 6 hours of PvE to unlock all 3. Don't forget to check every once in a while if you unlocked one, so you don't waste more time than needed.

Comment: So far I have found that for Hunter Way of a Thousand Cuts it's the quantity of enemies which count, not the number of super uses.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tried it out with my Warlock. Currently was at 51%.
Killed exactly 1 enemy (a dreg) with a grenade and got 1%

[image]

Then I killed another enemy. This time a vandal. Another 1%

[image]

The next was a captain. He's also only worth 1%

[image]

Lastly, a servitor. Even those are worth just 1%

[image]

It seems that each enemy killed with a class ability or super adds 1% to your completion (at least for warlock-dawnblade subclass).

Comment: I thought that only super kills counted?

Comment: Pretty sure it's any abilities related to that subclass (i.e. grenade, special melee, super)

Comment: Yes, Chase is right. Though I have a feeling that when the expansion came out that only super and melee ability kills counted, but I have no proof for that .